# [Vue warn]: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined?"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, webpack-2

Could someone help me understand the behavior of the code below?:

```js
wrapperProperties () {
  let properties = this.getToValueOf('wrapper', {})
  [properties['type'], properties['message']] = this.defineValidationState()
  return properties
}
```

I'm getting the following warning:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined"

When I add any variable between the `let` keyword and destructuring assignment the code completed successfully:

```js
wrapperProperties () {
  let properties = this.getToValueOf('wrapper', {}), mysteriousVar
  [properties['type'], properties['message']] = this.defineValidationState()
  return properties
}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
let properties = this.getToValueOf('wrapper', {})
[properties['type'], properties['message']]
```

Is interpreted as this:

```
let properties = this.getToValueOf('wrapper', {})[properties['type'], properties['message']]
```

So instead of destructuring it is interpreted as property access using the `[]` syntax.

You should either insert semicolons at the end of every statement or you should really read and understand the standard.js coding standard. According to standard.js you **must** put a semicolon at the beginning of every line that starts with `{` or `[`.

I personally prefere classic "Douglas Crockford" style so I'd add a semicolon at the end of every statement. But either way works:

"Crockford" style:

```
wrapperProperties () {
  let properties = this.getToValueOf('wrapper', {});
  [properties['type'], properties['message']] = this.defineValidationState();
  return properties;
}
```

Standard.js style:

```
wrapperProperties () {
  let properties = this.getToValueOf('wrapper', {})
  ;[properties['type'], properties['message']] = this.defineValidationState()
  return properties
}
```